# PHP and ob_end_clean function

Tags: php

I am look at PHP - *Laravel* framework source code, in they error.php file, I have found this line.

```
**ob_get_level() and ob_end_clean();**
```

just want to know what is purpose of above code?

regards,

anru

Comment: RTM's [ob_get_level()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) & [ob_end_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)

Comment: Maybe check the manual?

Comment: the guy give me a "-", did you actually read my question? I am asking for 'purpose' of code , not meaning of 'function'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has a feature called [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). When implemented, the output of echo, print or whatever will be buffered instead of going directly to php's output. This is useful if you need to analyze the output afterwards, or even throw it away.

Normal use can be similar to the following:

```
ob_start();
echo "bla bla ...";

// ... more code

// grab contents of the output buffer
$content = ob_get_contents();

// analyze it ...
if(content_looks_good($content)) {
    ob_end_flush();
} else {
    echo "bad content";
    ob_end_clean(); // throw buffer contents away
}
```

However this was just an example. There is a ton of different ways to use output buffering.

---

The code you've shown just throws the buffer contents away. I don't know the reason as I don't know which code you quoted.

Explanation of syntax:

[`ob_get_level()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) will return the current nesting level of the output buffer. If it is greater than zero, php will use the value as boolean `true` and therefore executes [`ob_end_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) what cleans the buffer.

It is the same as the following statement, which might be better to understand:

```
if(ob_get_level() > 0) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means "if something is already buffered - clear buffer"

The same can be written as

```
if (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*"If `ob_get_level()` returns a 'truthy' value (is not 0 but higher), an output buffer is active, let's end it & discard it's contents."*

Normally, you'd know you started on output buffer. In frameworks, you don't know what your users might do to buffers, so check for an active one first.